# Prevent port from being used by anything but one application

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, port, port-forwarding

Is there a way to make only java be allowed to use a certain port?

OS: Windows Web Server 2008 R2

No access to router (hosted box).

Comment: You need to put a lot more detail in your question please, at least your OS.

Comment: I added some stuff, anything else? (also added which application now: java)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a personal firewall to enforce a rule for this specific behavior. For example, Windows Firewall with Advanced Security snap-in supports rules on port and application level. 
See Microsoft's documentation on [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc754274.aspx)
or
this page for a [quick tutorial on rule setup](http://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/).